# Xamarin Studio UI Designer throws UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency Exception

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am designing the UI for my iOS app with the Xamarin Studio UI Designer. In one of my view controllers, I have a UITableView. If I add some local dummy data to the table, the UI designer renders the view controller just fine. However, when I try to add some real data to the table (from a RESTful web service) the UI designer won't render the view controller. The following error message appears instead:

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException was thrown.

Objective-C exception thrown. Name:
UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency Reason: child view
controller: <DashboardPageViewController: 0x7c7818c0> should have
parent view controller: (null) but actual parent is: <UIViewController:
0x7974e4e0>
```

I can understand from various sources that this exception can be thrown was assigning a view controller to the wrong parent. However, I have only added the view controller in the UI designer and not done any explicit parent assignments. It is also odd, that the UI designer only seems to fail when I fetch my data from the internet.

EDIT: I should add, that the app runs without issues in the emulator no matter what data I use.

Any help on this matter is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you contact xamarin at contact@xamarin.com. We'll need the full stack trace as well as the log files in order to diagnose the issue. I suspect the problem is that an exception is being thrown from your code when it's running inside the designer and it's crashing things in unexpected places.